# Python concatenate string for conditions used in a generator expression

Tags: python, if-statement, concatenation, generator-expression

I have a set of conditions for a generator expression which will vary, and if possible, I thought to try concatenate the conditions as a string, and use this string variable inside the generator expression:

The following works fine:

```
Total = sum(sale["Date"] == date for sale in Sales_Store)
```

Where date is an integer, and Sales_Store a list of dictionaries with same keys, "Date" is one of the key names. it returns the number of sales in the sales store which satisfy this condition.

But this gives error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

```
strTest = "sale[\"Date\"] == date for sale in Sales_Store"
Total = sum(strTest)
```

Of course, I only want this condition in the generator expression if a certain other condition holds true, and have several other conditions to concatenate with this, each condition only applying in certain circumstances.

So do you know if there is way to make this concatenation work?

Comment: Nitpick: you don't have a list comprehension, you have a generator expression.

Comment: Strings are not executable code. Python won't look at a string and execute it if it could possibly be.

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque: the question is pretty clear without more code. I'm not sure what you expect to learn from 'full code'. For incomplete problems we ask for an [MCVE], never the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are not executable code. Python won't look at a string and execute it if it could possibly be. You need to express your conditions differently.

You could just create a function that given *one* dictionary returns a boolean; for a simple expression you can create that function using the `lambda` syntax:

```
condition = lambda d: d['Date'] == date
```

for larger tests you can use a `def condition(d):` function definition and use multiple statements, etc. Functions are executable expressions!

Then use that in a [`map()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply the condition to each dictionary:

```
sum(map(condition, Sales_Store))
```

If you need to *dynamically* change the conditions, then build a sequence of tests, and use the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) or [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) functions to combine these tests:

```
conditions = (test1, test2, test3)
all_conditions = lambda d: all(t(d) for t in conditions)
any_condition = lambda d: any(t(d) for t in conditions)

all_conditions_sum = map(all_conditions, Sales_Store)
any_conditions_sum = map(any_conditions, Sales_Store)
```

As you can probably tell from the function names, `any()` will return `True` if *one* of the tests is true, `all()` if *all* of the tests are true.

How you select the tests to go into the `conditions` sequence is up to you. You could, for example, have a dictionary mapping a user-friendly string to a function and let an end-user decide.

Comment: To add to this, the reason why OP has that specific error is because the `sum` function starts with the value 0 by default and adds values to it; that is where the `int` is coming from.

Comment: Very helpful @Martijn Pieters, fyi what I should have mentioned probably is that the content of conditions actually depends on content of current 'sale' dictionary within the 'Sales_Store' list.

Comment: fyi if anyone else reads this one day, I did    Total = sum(conditions(sale, date, end, p_id, c_id, s_id, r_id) for sale in Sales_Store)     and then as @Martijn suggestion, created function    def conditions (sal,...):    where had to change each variable name because it's function, bit ugly but it worked, this was for certain website challenge, so in real life would use proper database app I guess but not an option I think for this. fyi my final code worked for 10 out of 12 test inputs, timed out for other 2, I guess this was overall algo though, sorry still getting used markdown in comment.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried int() function convert everything to integers before addition?

Comment: `bool` is a subclass of `int`, `True` and `False` **are integers already**, values `1` and `0`. How is this going to help with extracting the conditions out to a separate entity?